# How to smoothly login through openvpn with 2 factor auth?

Tags: login, password, vpn, openvpn, authentication

I have a openvpn set up with 2 factor authentication via Google Authenticator app.

In connection details I filled *User name* and *Password* (*User key password* empty). When I login for the 1st time I get popup to fill in authentication code from Google app. After I do that though, the passwords gets overriden with this number code from the app. So next time I try to login there is popup for password and after that another popup for the Google app.

Can this be somehow fix to either:

- save the password and show popup only for Google app
- save the password and use some sort of script/app/hack so the authentication code from Google is filled automatically? (So I don't have to deal with popups? :) )

It's fresh installation of Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: What application exactly are you trying to log into?

Comment: @Sebastian just generally through default Ubuntu network manager

Comment: I am not aware that it has 2FA, The one I use allows me to save username & password per connection. In general, you won't be able to automatically enter the 2FA code since it changes each time, but you should be able to save your username & password for the connection permanently, or use a password manager for it.

Comment: @Sebastian OP is not asking to save OTP but the password. I ran into the same issue and have been pulling out my hair. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and the issue also exists in the previous Ubuntu versions. I know this can be fixed because openvpn client in windows 10 saves the password just fine.

Comment: It seems like this is a bug in Ubuntu. Every time one enters a one time password, it replaces the stored ordinary password. Therefore it works the first time, but the second time the password will be wrong and it will ask you to type it again.

Comment: @ThomasBjørnsonLarsen yes, exactly. Did you find some alternative?

Comment: This was an issue in 18.04 and still is an issue in 20.04 as @Rico Chen mentioned. Perhaps file as a bug?

Comment: The issue is still there on Ubuntu 20. The authentication code is getting replaced by the static password. Did someone find a solution?

Comment: There are bugs opened for the issue. Please vote for them: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/97
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1886728

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not solution, but [workaround](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-openvpn/-/issues/12#note_1187736)

#### Guide

0. Expected that VPN successfully configured.
   [image]
   [image]

   > Note: select **"Store the password for all users"**
   > [image]
1. Get the list of VPN connections in command line, and find the target connection:

   ```sh
   nmcli connection show
   ```

   [image]
2. Create a post-down script file, which will run every time when connection closed:

   ```sh
   sudo touch /etc/network/if-post-down.d/overwrite-vpn-password
   ```
3. Put next content inside:
   */etc/network/if-post-down.d/overwrite-vpn-password*

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh

   nmcli connection modify NAME_OR_UUID vpn.secrets password=MY_PASSWORD
   ```

   [image]
4. Make file executable:

   ```sh
   sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-post-down.d/overwrite-vpn-password
   ```
5. Done!

#### What's happen?

When you enter 2FA code, and VPN connection succeed, it updates secret password. This script will be executed every time when ANY connection closed (VPN for example), and will modify secrets of connection config using [nmcli](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html) with hardcoded values.

Comment: I just edited the post, until a community member approves it, 

*Important note, at the VPN settings, navigate yourself to the password input and click on the right icon, then select Store the password for all users. I noticed that it didn't work when I ran the command as root, which breaks the rest of the process.

Comment: @gtzinos thanks for pointing it

Comment: You are welcome bro!

Comment: What OpenVPN manager is this? Is it something open-source?

Comment: Default VPN manager in Ubuntu

Comment: it is the openvpn plugin for NetworkManager which is the UI tool used for network management in Gnome